# In GVIM how can we search and highlight while keeping the previous search highlighted

Tags: vim

In GVIM how can we search and highlight while keeping the previous search highlighted.
Example As we search a new pattern the previous pattern gets un-highlighted.

So is ter a way we can retain the previous search highlighted while searching new patterns simultaneously.

regards

Answer (score 6):

For your second search you can use

```
:2match Search /pattern/
```

For a third search term you can use :3match.

If you don't want to type this, you can put a command like this in `.vimrc`

```
command -nargs=1 S2 :2match search /<args>/
```

And in VIm just type `:S2 pattern`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`/`<kbd>CTRL-R</kbd><kbd>CTRL-O</kbd>`/\|pattern`

Which will insert current search pattern, and start an alternative.

Comment: Thank u guys for the answer,but how do unhighlight them all together as when i do :set nohl it only works for either of the pattern's u searched for. So how do u unhighlight them                                           Regards

Comment: hello guys,Any solution for this query

Comment: @James bond: don't really understand. Could you put an illustrated (forged) example on the question side, of what you want (detailed)?

Comment: @Jamesbond You probably don't really want to use `set nohl`, as that will turn off search highlighting, not just clear the current highlight. Try this if you have two searches: `:nohlsearch|2match none`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this matching commands...

```
:sy[ntax] match {group-name} [{options}] [excludenl] {pattern} [{options}]
```

if you wants to search and highlight **Apple** with **Red** color and **Mango** with **Yellow** and **Grape** with **Blue** use this:

```
:highlight col1 guibg=Red guifg=White
:syntax match col1 /Apple/
:highlight col2 guibg=Yellow guifg=Black
:syntax match col2 /Mango/
:highlight col3 guibg=Blue guifg=White
:syntax match col3 /Grape/
```